# cocoa:Can not find webView object

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4, xcode4.3

Click the button webView load the page.Can not find webView object.

[image]

**Code download：**

http://code.google.com/p/kacperwangbuttontab/downloads/list

Comment: Did you add the WebKit framework to your project?

Comment: There are two classes , a class declaration webView, another class call webView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

webView is a property of your window instance (that you declared in AppWindow.h), so you need to get a reference to that somehow.  One way to do that is to put this line in your mouseUp method:

WebView *webView = [(AppWindow *)self.superview.window webView];

(you also need to import "AppWindow.h" into ButtonStyle.m)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't declared a variable named `webView` that's visible within that `mouseUp:` method.

If you have a property by that name, then you need to access it using property syntax: `self.webView`, rather than `webView`.

Otherwise, make sure that you named the variable correctly, that you are referring to it by the name you gave it, that you declared it in the correct place, and that you use it within the scope in which you declared it.

If you meant for `webView` to exist as a local variable (existing only within `mouseUp:`), you need to declare it above the highlighted message within the same method, and assign a WebView to it.

If you meant for `webView` to be an instance variable, then you need to declare it in the ButtonStyle class's instance variables section and assign a WebView to it in either `mouseUp:` or, more probably, another method that is called earlier.

If you want to create the WebView in a nib, then you should declare `webView` as an outlet property, and access it with the property-access syntax I showed above.